# Print Job submitted to printer, working with virtual printer but not the real printer. Java

Tags: java, printing

I am new to java and is having problem with print service in java. I am trying to create a desktop application in Java which on installed in a system, calls an api, get the results back and prints.

The print service is called only when we get result from the api. So my problem is that when I tried this application in my windows machine it works exactly the way I wanted with the virtual printer when I make that the default printer, but doesn't works with my real printer even though it is made as the default printer.

Does we need to add some configuration or port number in order to work in real printer? here is the source code

```
try {
    HttpEntity entity = orderRes.getEntity();

    if (entity != null){
        //String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        byte[] byteSRC = Base64.decodeBase64(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        System.out.println(service);
        DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
        printJob.addPrintJobListener(new ClientApiPrintTask.JobCompleteMonitor());
        if(byteSRC != null) {
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(byteSRC, flavor, null);
            printJob.print(doc, null);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    //System.out.println("Exiting app");
} catch (PrintException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ClientApiPrintTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ClientApiPrintTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    res.close();
}
```

I have added a print job listener to find the issue and what I can find is that PrintJobEvent `printDataTransferCompleted` and `printJobNoMoreEvents` are invoked but not the `printJobCompleted` or `printJobFailed`. I am using `JDK version 1.7.0_65` for development.